# How can I manipulate the number of points visible according to scale?

Tags: dem, labeling, scale, visibility

I've gotten trillions of points extracted from a DEM and they are to be labelled. It's fine at scales such as 1:500 but it gets too cluttered especially if I need to make maps of this with scales up to 1:24000. Is there any way to make less points visible as the user zooms out without creating new feature classes?

A bit more about the data: the points are in a grid fashion and there is no way of identifying them by row or column which makes select by location quite difficult.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what software are you representing the data in?

Comment: @artwork21 I'm using ArcGIS but I also have QGIS at my disposal.

Comment: When you say "without creating new feature classes", you mean without creating a new layer of lower-resolution elevation data?

Comment: @barrycarter yes, because that would make the WMS I'm trying to make too crowded with data.

Comment: For every 5x5 block of data (for example), could you pick a "representative point" to display at lower zoom? This is similar to creating a lower-zoom layer, but slightly more efficient.